# PDF management on WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to create an e-Library page in WordPress. I want on this page to be listed all the pdf that I have on media library. I want to be able to list them, search by name, filter by date or category. I'm using [media-category-library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-category-library/) plugin but i don't like it very much, because of the search page..
Which is the best plugin to do this, I'm new in WordPress and I don't have an idea how to define which plugin is the best? Can somebody help me?